# Change "effective home" directory on Linux system

Tags: linux, python, home, pip

I have to run some Python code on a remote machine which has fairly heavy dependencies. My home directory `(.../home/d/my-name)` has a very small amount of disk space, so I typically use a different directory `(/local/my-name)` which has a large disk mounted as my "effective" home directory.

When trying to install dependencies I run out of space in my home directory. As such, I'd like all these dependencies to be stored in the `local` dir (and am perfectly fine with this being the default for the future). I am using Conda environments and running pip inside of them. I understand that I can tell pip to store things places other than home, but that this can cause issues with software referencing home. As such, I hope to effectively change my home directory to be located in `local`. Is this possible? I do not have sudo privileges if that is relevant.

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Answer (score 2):

`move-and-symlink` is the traditional solution to problems like this.

e.g. if you want to move the entire `~/lib/` directory to `/local/my-name`:

```
mv ~/lib/ /local/my-name/
ln -sf /local/my-name/lib/ ~/
```

BTW, while the trailing `/` on the end of the symlink source `/local/my-name/lib/` isn't required, I strongly recommend it - it makes tab-completion work better in bash.

If you have write access to your home directory's parent dir (e.g. with sudo), you can even move your entire home directory to /local.  You could also use `usermod -m -d` to change your home directory in `/etc/passwd`.